# Trying to import from class for pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, pytest

This feels like a silly question, but I am trying to import a class to do testing with pytest and it does not seem to want to work. I am not sure why it is still greyed out when I look at it in pycharm.

Here is my code

```
from classes import *

class Test:
    def setup_method(self):
        self.tv1 = power(True)

    def teardown_method(self):
        del self.tv1

    def test_power(self):
        assert power(True) is True
        assert power(False) is False
```

[image: Greyed out in pycharm]

Here is part of the class file:

classes.py is the file name.

```
class Television:
    """
    A class building functions for a remote control object

    Global variables for each function use
    :param MIN_CHANNEL: Channel cannot decrease beyond this
    :param MAX_CHANNEL: Channel cannot increase beyond this
    :param MIN_VOLUME: Volume cannot decrease beyond this
    :param MAX_VOLUME: Volume cannot increase beyond this
    """

    MIN_CHANNEL = 0
    MAX_CHANNEL = 3

    MIN_VOLUME = 0
    MAX_VOLUME = 2

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """
        Constructor to create initial state of television object
        :param channel: Value to store channel number
        :param volume: Value to store volume level
        :param status: Value to store if TV is on or off
        """

        self.__channel = Television.MIN_CHANNEL                # - Create a private variable to store the TV channel. It should be set to the minimum TV channel by default.
        self.__volume = Television.MIN_VOLUME                  # - Create a private variable to store the TV volume. It should be set to the minimum TV volume by default.
        self.__status = False                           # - Create a private variable to store the TV status. The TV should start when it is off.


    def power(self) -> None:
        """
        Method to change status of the TV
        :return: On or Off status of TV
        """

        if self.__status == False:                      # - This method should be used to turn the TV on/off.
            self.__status = True                       # - If called on a TV object that is off, the TV object should be turned on.
        else:
            self.__status = False                       # - If called on a TV object that is on, the TV object should be turned off.
```

Comment: Show your classes file

Comment: It's because you have unused imports

Comment: Added class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on with this example code so I'll try to address some of them here:

**Object instantiation**

It looks like you wrote the `power` function as a method of the `Television` class, hence why it is not available to use directly. Thus instead of this:

```
from classes import *
power()
```

You will need to instantiate the object first and then call the method on the instantiated object:

```
tv = Television()
tv.power()
```

The power state in this example is only maintained in the instance of `Television` assigned to the `tv` variable above.

**Rewriting the tests**

Your power method toggles the power but you do not provide a way to access the internal state for testing (it's not good practice to access the attribute prefixed with an `_` or `__`). You could have that method return the new state, or provide a property method that returns the state from the internal variable. For the example here I will choose the former:

```
    # Note we change the return type to bool
    def power(self) -> bool:
        # your power function
        # Add this return statement
        return self.__status
```

Now we don't need to explicitly delete objects in Python (although you can), because the garbage collector will handle the object destruction. So we can simply write our test as:

```
    def test_power(self):
        tv = Television()
        assert tv.power()
        assert not tv.power()
```

**Simplifying toggle method**

To toggle the value you just want to negate the boolean:

```
self.__status = not self.__status
```

**Private class members**

While Python doesn't enforce public/private attributes on objects by default, a single underscore is the [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) (a common style guide) way of showing that a variable is "internal".

> _single_leading_underscore: weak “internal use” indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.

**Specifying a sources root**

PyCharm also has to know which directory (or directories) in your project it should use to resolve imports. To tell PyCharm about this you can mark the directory containing the `classes.py` and `test_classes.py` file as a "Sources Root". Right click (or Ctrl-Click on Mac) the directory in the file tree on the left and then choose `Mark Directory as` > `Sources Root`. You may not need to do this, depending on how you set up your PyCharm project.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Still learning and clear explanations like this are very helpful